# Fast Iteration of Dictionary(string, List>

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List of 1.5 million records. I need to iterate through this List around 300 times to pull out certain records for performing calculations on. I assumed that converting my List to a Dictionary would make my lookups faster during the iteration.

My List is comprised of a class like this:

```
class SummaryRecord
{
    public int CalcData { get; set; }
    public string Id2 { get; set; }
    public string Id2 { get; set; }
}
```

Since I have 2 ids that make a record unique, I convert my list to a Dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, SummaryRecord> dictSummaries = summaries.ToDictionary(
    e => e.Id1 + "+" + e.Id2 + "+" + e.CalcData);
```

I then loop through a secondary list of 300 ID pairs to pull out the records from the big list.

```
foreach(var ids in listOfIds)
{
    var filteredData = from d in dictSummaries
                       where
                       d.Key.Contains(ids.Id1 + "+" + ids.Id2)
                       select d;

    //perform operation on filteredData here. This code is slow as well.
    filteredData.Count()
}
```

This is obviously not very efficient based on what I see performance-wise as it takes around 1 second (times 300 seconds) to perform each iteration. How can I make the process of querying the records faster?

Comment: Afaik a dictionary will perfom better on lookups but not guaranteed to do it on iterations as well...

Comment: I answered below. But I want to clarify something. Since I see you use .Count(), are you expecting that there could possibly be more than 1 entry in the dictionary with the same key? Because this is impossible and will throw an exception when you try the second insert.

Comment: A dictionary is going to be slower to iterate than a `List`.  The advantage of a `Dictionary` is that, in general, *you don't need to iterate it at all* when you're using it properly.  What are the *actual* requirements of your program.

Comment: *stringly* typed dictionary would be even slower - not sure why you'd convert key to string instead of providing comparer...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I agree. He could just keep his list of SummaryRecord objects, if he implements IComparable or a Comparer. Then he can do a binary search on an ordered list.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You state you have you have 2 ids that make a record unique.  Why in world would you need to search e.Id1 + "+" + e.Id2 + "+" + e.CalcData for ids.Id1 + "+" + ids.Id2?   Why put it in a Dictionary to do that?  You are not using the what a Dictionary does.

Answer (score 3):

As is, you are not actually using the power of the dictionary. You query will iterate over every record in the dictionary checking for the condition you gave.

Since you have the full key, you should just do a direct lookup of each key:

`string key = ids.Id1 + "+" + ids.Id2;
SummaryRecord summaryRecord = dictSummaries[key];`

If you are not sure that key exists, make sure to do a [TryGetValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead or do a [ContainsKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) check.

Comment: He's seeing if the key contains a value, not if it's equal to a value.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but it seems like he was just misusing .Contains() and probably meant to use .Equals().

Comment: Perhaps.  Or perhaps he actually does want to find values where the key contains a value, rather than where it equals a value.

Comment: @Servy "Since I have 2 ids that make a record unique"

Comment: @Blam What bearing does that have on whether or not he's looking up items based on equality or a contains operation?  That he has a composite key doesn't prevent either operations from being possible requirements.

Comment: @Servy Easy.   That is how I read it.  I think he mean to do a Key lookup and not a string contains.   It has a big bearing on speed and that was his expectation.

Comment: @Blam Why does the fact that he have a composite key mean that he wants to lookup a key given an entire key, rather than a partial key?  The fact that the key is a composite key doesn't mean that he won't ever want to see if that key contains a value, rather than that it's equal to a value.  The fact that looking up an exact key is faster doesn't mean that his actual requirements aren't to lookup the results from a partial key.  If that's his actual requirement then the answer *doesn't work*, and so how fast it is is *irrelevant* if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Servy Easy.  That is how I read "since I have 2 ids that make a record unique".  Really he is combing ids.Id1 + "+" + ids.Id2 to create a key and then he searches on ids.Id1 + "+" + ids.Id2 and what he want to do just see if that key contains a value.   If he was looking for substrings he would be looking in id1 and id2 separately.

Comment: @Blam The fact that he has a composite key in no way implies that he's looking for an exact match of that key, rather than a partial match.  He might be, and he might not be.  His code indicates he isn't looking for an exact match.  If what he actually wants is an exact match instead, then he would need to say that.  So far he has refused to clarify.

Comment: @sevy So he created a unique composite key and put it in a dictionary and that in not way implies he wants to perform a unique match?   Cool

Comment: @Blam Considering in his most recent revision he specifically stated that he's searching using only a part of the key, and that he expects multiple results, conclusively stating that both answers are wrong, apparently.  But yes, the fact that items all have a unique key doesn't imply that one is always searching using a complete key.  One can search through a list of unique keys using a partial key, excepting multiple results.  The OP is apparently *in* such a position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78834/discussion-between-blam-and-servy).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using 3 fields as key for your dictionary

> summaries.ToDictionary(
>       e => e.Id1 + "+" + e.Id2 + "+" + e.CalcData);

I believe that is possible to have multiples, id1+id2.
If thats the case you could use ToLookup, instead of ToDictionary.

```
var lookup = summaries.ToLookup(e => e.Id1 + "+" + e.Id2);
```

and then

```
foreach(var ids in listOfIds)
{
    var filteredData = lookup[ids.Id1 + "+" + ids.Id2];

    //perform operation on filteredData here. This code is slow as well.
    filteredData.Count()
}
```

Now if is not possible to have multiples id1 + id2, why are you concatenating id1 + id2 **+ CalcData**?

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure you are getting a call to [String.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx).
You are iterating EACH key in the dictionary and testing the key contains another string.
So "prekey1key2" contains "key1key2.
If you intend to get an exact lookup be aware that is not what you are getting (and you are not utilizing Dictionary HashBuckets at all).

You are iterating each record.  You are not using a dictionary lookup at all. 
Worse yet you are iterating each record in the Dictionary for each row in listOfIds.

If ID1 and ID2 form a unique key then use that as the key and look it up directly like the answer by Kevin
This is Hashed lookup and is smoking fast

```
SummaryRecord summaryRecord = dictSummaries[key];
```

Also selects ID1, ID2 that hash well.
Could you use two int16 that you can combine into an Int32?
You could go to so far as to override GetHashCode with the real key.
And override Equals.

Another way to go at this

```
class SummaryRecord
{
    public int CalcData { get; set; }
    public string Key { get { return Id1 + Id2; } 
    public string Id2 { get; set; }
    public string Id2 { get; set; }
}
private HashSet<String> keyToFind = new  HashSet<String>() {"key1","key2"}; 
var filteredData = from d in dictSummaries.where(x => keyToFind.Contains(x.key));
```

That Contains will be a HashBucket lookup.
You are still iterating the Dictionary but now you have a very efficient comparison.
And the benefit here is you are only iterating the Dictionary once.
Try this first.